# Linearity, Causality and Stability of a System

Tags: linear-systems, homework, stability, causality

Consider a system:

$$
y[n] = y[n-1] + u[n],
$$

where $y[n]$ is the output and $u[n]$ is the unit step function.

Is this system causal, linear, time-invariant and stable ?

My attempt at the question is that for the systems without any input, we can never talk about all the properties above as they are related to input/output relationships of the system, whereas there are is no input in the system.

However, I'm inclined to think about the system as follows:

$$
y[n] = y[n-1] + \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} 0 . x[i] + u[n].
$$

So trivially, the system is non-linear as it produces non-zero output for zero input, non-causal as it depends on future inputs, unstable as no matter the input, the output is unbounded and time-variant as if we delay the input, the output stays the same.

Comment: Please define your symbols. Is u[n] the input or the unit step function? In order for anything to qualify as a system, you need to have an input and an output

Comment: @Hilmar The question is updated. $u[n]$ is the unit step function. I agree with your comment that for a system, we need an input. However, as I proposed above, we can think of this as a collection of systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **interpratation** (that belongs to you) that output $y[n]$ is given by the recursion relation $$y[n] = y[n-1] + u[n]$$ no matter what the input $x[n]$ is, then the following conclusions can be made about the linearity, time-invariance, stability and causality of the system.

First let's solve the output for $y[n]$

i.For $n<0$, since $u[n]=0$, we have $$y[n] = y[n-1]$$ which implies that $y[-1]=y[-2]=...y[-N]...= K$ for all $n < 0$

ii.For $n\geq0$, since $u[n]=1$, then we have
$$y[n] = y[n-1] + 1$$ which can be recursively solved to get

\begin{align}
y[0] &= y[-1] + 1 = K +1 \\
y[1] &= y[0] + 1 = (K+1) +1 = K+2 \\
y[2] &= y[1] + 1 = K +3 \\
&...\\
y[n] &= y[n-1] + 1 = K +(n+1) \\
\end{align}

Combining them yields: $$\boxed{y[n] = K + (n+1) u[n] }$$ for all $n$ as th fixed-unique output of the system for all inputs $x[n]$

Then we analyse the system for its properties:

1. The system is **non-linear**:
   It's so evident since the system has a fixed, unique output for every input
   it's a non-linear system as it **cannot** satisfy $$\mathcal{T}\{a x_1[n]+ b x_2[n] \} = a \mathcal{T}\{x_1[n] \} + b\mathcal{T}\{x_2[n]\} $$
2. The system is **time-varying**:
   Again shifting the input have no effect on the output (which is fixed) so it cannot satisfy $$ y[n-d] = \mathcal{T}\{x[n-d] \}$$
   **NOTE:** Does this make any sense? The system is already a **fixed** one. It has a fixed output for every input. Hence effectively nothing varies in its output. Nevertheless I called it as time-varying, because evidently it cannot saitsfy the time-invariance constraint.
3. The system is **causal**: it only depends on the past value of the output and it does not depend on any value of the input so it does not violate causality.
4. The system is **unstable**: as for a bounded input $x[n] = \delta[n]$ the output is $y[n] = K + (n+1) u[n]$ which grows unbounded as $n$ goes to infinity.
5. The system is not invertible.
6. The system can be implemented with and without any memory requirement.

Comment: @ubaabd Hi! Now you have an answer. I hope it clarifies your concerns... Please indicate so by a comment, upvote (or downvote?) or acceptance. These are floating (zombie) questions :-) Someone posts a question and forgets it ?

Comment: Your interpretation of the input/output relationship is great. I have developed the feeling that the question can be answered in two ways: First, philosophically, the question doesn't make any sense as all the four properties are properties for input/output relationships. Second, mathematically, your answer makes sense, specially for stability. However, for causality, I guess the system is not unique and can represent a casual as well as noncausal system, as I mentioned in my question. I am up voting your answer because it answers the questions on strict mathematics grounds.

Comment: Actually it's a degenerate system. It's just like a system which outputs a constant $M$ for all n. The system is causal in the sense that you can compute it's output $y[n]$ in **real-time** for all $n$ considering $n$ refers to time.

Comment: I have low reputation on dspstack. My up-votes won't appear.

Comment: oh sorry, nevermind ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is over 2 years old now, I think it's interesting to consider the solution, assuming that the original interpretation was incorrect, and that $u[n]$ represents the system input, not the unit step sequence.  If so, then the first thing to recognize is that the system is just an accumulator.  For a time-domain demonstration, simply make repeated substitutions into the difference equation.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
    y[n] & = & y[n-1] + x[n] \\
    & = & y[n-2] + x[n-1] + x[n] \\
    & = & y[n-3] + x[n-2] + x[n-1] + x[n] \\
    & = & y[n-4] + x[n-3] + x[n-2] + x[n-1] + x[n] \\
    & \vdots & \\
    y[n] & = & \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x[n-m]
\end{array}$$

You can also show this using the $z$-transform,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
    Y(z) & = & z^{-1} Y(z) + X(z) \\
    H(z) = \dfrac{Y(z)}{X(z)} & = & \dfrac{1}{1 - x^{-1}} \\
    h[n] & = & \mbox{unit step sequence} \\
    \Rightarrow y[n] & = & \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x[n-m].
\end{array}$$

At this point, one can use the standard techniques to test if the system is linear, time-invariant, causal and stable.

Linearity: Define two input signals $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$, with corresponding outputs $y_1[n]$ and $y_2[n]$,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
    y_1[n] & = & \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_1[n-m] \\
    y_2[n] & = & \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_2[n-m]
\end{array}$$

Now define a third input signal that is a linear combination of the others,
$$ x_3[n] = a x_1[n] + b x_2[n]. $$

The output in response to $x_3[n]$ is

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
    y_3[n] & = & \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_3[n-m] \\
    & = & \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left( a x_1[n-m] + b x_2[n-m] \right) \\
    & = & a \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_1[n-m] 
    + b \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_2[n-m]  \\
    & = & a y_1[n] + b y_2[n].
\end{array}$$

Therefore the system is linear.

Time-Invariance: Using $x_1[n]$ and $y_1[n]$ as an input-output pair, define the input
$$x_2[n] = x_1[n-N]$$.

The corresponding output is
$$ y_2[n] = \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_2[n-m]
= \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_1[n-N-m] 
= y_1[n-N]. $$

Therefore the system is time-invariant.

Causality: The system is causal by inspection, as $y[n]$ depends on $x[n-m]$ only for $m \geq 0$.

Stability: Let $x[n]$ be the bounded input signal that is 1 for all $n$.  the output $y[n]$ is the sum of all present and previous inputs, which will diverge to infinity for all $n$.  Therefore the system is unstable.